# Flutter Firebase Storage returning FirebaseApiNotAvailableException

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

From a Flutter app, I am trying to determine the download URL of an image within Firebase Storage. For testing, there are **no** auth security rules applied (set as 'allow read, write;') or auth applied in the app. When using the following method,

```
Future<String> _getDownloadImageUrl(String folder, String filename) async {
  String childpath = "$folder/$filename";
  StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(childpath);
  Future<String> durl = await ref.getDownloadURL();
  return durl;
}
```

I get the following error (when testing on Android device) :

> E/StorageUtil(): error getting token
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.google.firebase.FirebaseApiNotAvailableException: firebase-auth is
>   not linked, please fall back to unauthenticated mode.

The same app is querying (Firestore) database data OK (with no auth), but I'm not sure if I am missing a step, for example, such as explicitly performing an action relating to "unauthenticated mode" for Firebase Storage?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check your firebase storage rules?

You can find it in the rules tab on the storage page (shown below)

[image]

you will need to change

```
allow read, write: if request.auth!=null;
```

to

```
allow read, write: if true;
```

and check, but you will obviously want to change that before going to production.

With that aside you have a little typo in your code

```dart
Future<String> durl = await ref.getDownloadURL();
```

should be

```dart
String durl = await ref.getDownloadURL();
/// you can also use `final` and type inference will do the work for you.
```

Comment: I mentioned my current rules, so not that. There is something else missing here, and I cannot figure out what.

Comment: Ok did you add your sha-1 key to firebase and downloaded the latest google-services.json to your project?

Comment: Thanks. I had originally missed the sha-1 addition. I have now done this and applied the updated g-s.json file, however,  I am still unsuccessful, with the new error "error getting token... Please sign in before trying to get a token". What am I still missing?

Comment: Ultimately I found that (regardless of rules) I had to sign-in anonymously in order to access a ref's downloadUrl.